# How to show that two functions f and g are equal given that $f\:\subseteq g\:$ and dom g ⊆ dom f?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

My set theory textbook gives me the exercise, "assume that f and g are functions with $f\:\subseteq g\:$ and dom g ⊆ dom f.  Show that f = g."

One can quickly see that, given that $f\:\subseteq g\:\rightarrow \:\forall <x,y>\:\in f\:\rightarrow <x,y>\in g$, so it follows that $xFy\:\rightarrow \:xGy$

Is it necessary to prove the inverse case, $xGy\:\rightarrow \:xFy\:\:?$  Or, given that dom g ⊆ dom f, can we conclude now from the definition of a function that f = g?

Comment: You're basically just restating the hypothesis $f \subseteq g$, without using the other hypothesis. The meat of the proof is going to be showing that $g \subseteq f$. Start by supposing $\langle x, y \rangle \in g$. This implies $x \in \operatorname{dom} g \subseteq \operatorname{dom} f$. What does this give you?

Comment: I'm thinking if every x in the domain of g has some y in f, then g must be a subset of f

Comment: What I was hinting towards is more or less what Slugger put in their answer. But, as you say, having $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$ means that some $y'$ exists such that $\langle x, y'\rangle \in f$. But, prima facie, this doesn't necessarily have to be the same $y$ as in the original pair $\langle x, y \rangle \in g$. Slugger's argument shows that $y' = y$, so that they actually must be the same $y$, which proves $g \subseteq f$. This argument would fail if, for instance, $g$ were a general relation instead of a function!

Comment: For example, $f = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1, y \ge 0\}$ is a function (whose graph is a semicircle. If we let $g = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, then $g$ is not a function, but a relation. We still have $f \subseteq g$, and $\operatorname{dom} g \subseteq \operatorname{dom} f$ (they are both equal to $[-1, 1]$), but we don't have $f = g$.

Comment: That's a great point!

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $xGy \rightarrow xFy$ for all $<x,y> \in g$. So let $<x,y> \in g$. As $g$ is a function, there is only one such $y$ with $xGy$. As $\operatorname{dom}(g)\subset \operatorname{dom}(f)$, there is some $y'$ such that $x F y'$. Now by $f\subset g$ we must have $xGy'$. As there is only one unique $y$ with $xGy$, we must have $y'=y$ so that also $xFy$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for the equality of two functions, we have the following lemma:

**Lemma** (Criterion for Functional Equality). *Suppose $f,g$ are functions. Then $f=g$ if and only if, $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(g)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$.*

Now return to the proof of your problem.

*Proof.* To show $f=g$, it's sufficient to show two points:

1. $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(g)$. The $\supseteq$ is the assumption and $\subseteq$ follows from $f\subseteq g$.
2. $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$. It follows from $f\subseteq g$.

This completes the proof.